# In SQL, how to switching rows to column on dynamic results?

Tags: sql

I had an interview where the question asked me to list people's names but in 1 row instead of the column 'Names'. Ahead of time you wouldn't know how many names will return. I know for static transposing like months you can just do case when 12 times. However for dynamic scenarios like this, short of SQLserver with a handy PIVOT. How would one go about doing this without knowing how many columns it will be ahead of time in a regular interview whiteboard?

Thanks!

Comment: I would just aggregate them into a string or JSON array, rather than putting them in separate columns.

Comment: No way. SQL query can only return predetermined number of columns.

Comment: Gordon Linoff: Shoot maybe that's what the question was asking for... aggregation into one cell... Still, it wasn't clear. Not a very well thought out question. Thanks for the answers.